# Is there a debugging tool to know what LoC is changing your prop/state in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state, react-state-management, prop

I have been going at it the traditional way, by placing breakpoints, but I was wondering if there is a browser extension or a developer tool that tells you what line of code in your React application is changing the value of a `prop` or a `state` variable, or the object as a whole.

If this doesn't exist, what are some of the other way people debug their application when they are trying to understand where the value of a `prop` or `state` is getting changed?

Comment: This is specific to redux, but redux dev tools prints out the dispatch history

Comment: @Andrew, I wasn't actually looking for redux, but still good to know. Would you know of something when not using Redux?

Comment: I wish I knew myself :). Haven't heard of any tooling to do so in vanilla React.

Comment: there's one i didn't try it before but i found it , it might help you
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-state-trace